# Can charged boson be emergent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, emergent-properties

Dirac's initial interpretation of antimatter is the existence of Dirac Sea. However, it doesn't work for bosons since we can't invoke Fermi's exclusion principle. Goldstone boson can be emergent but it's neutral. Xiaogang Wen's work also revealed the possibility of an emergent QED structure from string-net condensation which shows fermi statistics and gauge interactions can be emergent. We also see emergent Lorentz Invariance in the low energy area of condensed matter system. W bosons are charged bosons. It seems impossible to me for charged boson to fit into Xiaogang Wen's "it from qubit" fantasy. Does anyone know the approach to this or related literature?

Comment: Dirac's interpretation is obsolete anyway. There is nothing wrong with charged boson (assuming you mean something like charged boson in an emergent U(1) gauge theory).

Comment: @Meng Cheng Would you elaborate on this emergent U(1) gauge theory? Is the boson set to be charged or emergently charged. Of course, there is nothing wrong with charged boson, W bosons exist. The real question here is whether charge conservation and antiparticles of boson can emerge rather than being taken for granted as the cornerstone in our theory.

Comment: @Bababeluma W bosons are charged because it was a SU(2) gauge boson but Higgs down to U(1). One can start with a string-net construction for SU(2) gauge theory, where the SU(2) gauge field is emergent. Then turn on a Higgs field (which can also be emergent) to get W bosons in the remaining emergent U(1) gauge theory.

Comment: @EverettYou I get the rough idea of yours but I can't fully grasp it. I'll look back into this when I have more experience in the field. Thanks a lot!